# GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a picture with the python sdk:

Code:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.current_user.access_token)
graph.put_object("me", "photos", name = "test", message = raw_picture_data)
```

But I get the error `"GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file"`. I don't think its a permissions issue as I've requested perms="user_photos,friends_photos,publish_stream". Does anyone know what this error means and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

I used this library to encode the image: http://atlee.ca/software/poster/

Add this to facebook.py:

```
from poster.encode import *
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

def put_photo(self, source, album_id=None, message=""):
    object_id = album_id or "me"

    register_openers()
    content_type,body = multipart_encode( [ ('message',message),('access_token',self.access_token),('source',source) ] )

    req = urllib2.Request("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/photos" % object_id, content_type,body )

    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        data = e.read() 
    try:
        response = _parse_json(data)
        if response.get("error"):
            raise GraphAPIError(response["error"].get("code", 1),response["error"]["message"])
    except ValueError:
        response = data

    return response
```

Call the function with the photo as a file like object:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
photo = open("myphoto.bmp","rb")
graph.put_photo(photo,"me","This is my brilliant photo")
```

The put_photo method has been submitted by someone (I forget who) as proposed a function to add to the API but it didn't work for me till I used poster to encode the image.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just battled with a similar error a bit. I did not use the SDK but just a POST to the graphapi. For me, this error happened when i didnt supply a filename to the file upload field in the "form" sent to facebook.
This is my code (poster - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/0.8.1)

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=%s'%model.facebook_token
file_param = MultipartParam(name = 'source',
                            filename = 'photo.jpg', #this is crucial!!!
                            fileobj = blob_reader) #the blob reader is the fileobject for the file (with read() method)
message_param = MultipartParam(name = 'message',
                               value = 'test message')                                

datagen, headers = multipart_encode([file_param,
                                     message_param])
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch(url, 
               payload = ''.join(datagen), 
               headers = headers,
               method = 'POST')     
return result.content
```